# App crash when running on iPhone 4.3 simulator after calling initWithNibName

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

I have the following code associated with pressing a button:

```
- (IBAction)favorites
{
    FavoritesActivityViewController *favorites = [[FavoritesActivityViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"FavoritesActivityViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:favorites.view];
}
```

When I run it on my iOS device (v 6.1) it works fine but when running on the 4.3 simulator it crashes when getting to calling addSubView. I have noticed that it crashes for any method I call on self.view like setTag etc so I guess the problem is with the returned object from initWithNibName

Thanks,
 Simon

Comment: add your crash report.

Comment: What does the console say about the crash? If you say it occurs for any method you call on `self.view` then it seems more likely that `self.view` is a invalid. What is `self`? Which class are you in?

Comment: This is the output: 
2013-08-28 10:43:48.703 dial2web[588:c303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
*** Call stack at first throw:
...more that dont fit here
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Comment: The class is UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `FavoritesActivityViewController` xib file, select **file inspector** tab, set Deployment target to ios 4.3 and uncheck **AutoLayout**. AutoLayout allows you to set constraints on UI controls. It is intended for iOS 6 and above only. To support nib for below iOS 6 versions, you must uncheck AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
FavoritesActivityViewController *favorites = [[FavoritesActivityViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FavoritesActivityViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:favorites.view];
```

Try this code...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file named "FavoritesActivityViewController.xib" is isexists and the property named "Class" of File's Owner is "FavoritesActivityViewController".